# LSTM weights batch normalization in CRNN architecture

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I tried batch normalization for the LSTM weights as per https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09025 on a Convolutional-RNN based network and I got notable improvement in training speed and performance. The features extracted from CNN are fed into 2 layers of Bidirectional LSTM.

In my first network I used few feature maps, so the input to the LSTM layers was 128. However, when I increase the input size (eg 256), I start getting NaNs for the LSTM output after some iterations (it works fine without batch normalization). I understand that this might be related to the division by small numbers. I also used an epsilon of 10^-6, but still getting NaNs.

Any ideas on what can I do to get rid of NaNs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having the same problem, using float64 data type instead of float32 helps in solving this issue. Of course this has memory implications, but I found it to be the only solution so far.

Comment: at which step do you use float64 ? Input ?